# URLs from my site appear in Google search results even though they are disallowed in robots.txt

Tags: seo, google, google-search, robots.txt

Here is content of my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /upload/
Disallow: /admin/
```

As you can see, I explicitly disallowed all robots to index the folders `images`, `upload` and `admin`. The problem is that one of my clients sent request for removing the content from the images folder because .pdf document from the `images` folder appeared in the google search results. Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong here, and why google indexed my folders?

Comment: In addition, I would recommend you to use the "Remove URLs" feature on Google Webmaster Tools and submit a removal request of your /images/ folder from Google's search results.

Comment: Same question was [asked on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25764711/1591669) previously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google isn't ignoring your robots.txt as robots.txt [does not tell Google not to list that content in its search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en). It tells Google not to *crawl* content. So Googlebot cannot find this content on its own. But if it does find this content it will still list it in the search results.

To keep content out of the search results you need to use the `x-robots-tag` HTTP header. It tells search engines not to index that content. If you're using Apache you can place a file called .htaccess in each of the mentioned directories with the following line in it:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

That will prevent the content of those directories to not appear in the search results.

Comment: With all due respect of course. You may need to re-read the page you linked to. *So, if a URL is disallowed in your robots.txt, that URL and its contents won't appear in Google Search results.* This was and remains the standard. I know that Google has been creating links in their SERPs for resources that are protected by robots.txt lately. Google likes to re-write the rules. However, they do disappear again as far as I know. I like the .htaccess solution you provided. Again- with respect.

Comment: @closetnoc `While Google won't crawl or index the content blocked by robots.txt, we might still find and index information about disallowed URLs from other places on the web. As a result, the URL address and, potentially, other publicly available information such as anchor text in links to the site can still appear in Google search results. ` That's from the page I linked to. There's another place (on another  page) where Google mentions they do this because sites like the CA DMV blocks their sites using robots.txt but Google wants to show their results as they are commonly searched for.

Comment: I'll see if I can find that link after lunch for reference.

Comment: [Found it.](http://www.webpronews.com/why-your-robotstxt-blocked-urls-may-show-up-in-google-2009-10)

Comment: Okay. Cool. That is what I meant by *I know that Google has been creating links in their SERPs for resources that are protected by robots.txt lately.* It has been my experience that these disappear, however, if a long standing robots.txt rule exists, Google should know better even though it does not appear that they do. This seems to be a new(ish) behavior (within the past couple of years). Thanks!

Comment: @closetnoc I guess what anyone should take away from this is that robots.txt is not the best way to exclude content from the search results an alternative methods should be employed.

Comment: I agree though it is a shame. Robots.txt should be enough in this case. It was, why it isn't anymore, I have no idea. Maybe laziness on Google's part, maybe Google rewriting the rules again, maybe the natural order of a larger net. Who know?

Comment: If I put X-Robots-Tag: noindex in /images/ folder, will this rule also be applied for /images/topImages/ folder?

Comment: Yes. If you want the contents of that folder to be indexed you just put the same file in that directory but with a value of index.

Answer (score -1):

While Google won’t crawl or index the content of pages blocked by robots.txt, we may still index the URLs if we find them on other pages on the web. As a result, the URL of the page and, potentially, other publicly available information such as anchor text in links to the site can appear in Google search results.

User-agent: *

Disallow:/images/

According to the above rule, all robots are denied access to the /images/ folder of a site. Additionally, a specific rule can be set to explicitly disallow access to all files within a folder:

`Disallow:/images/*`

Comment: `/images/` and `/images/*` are the same thing. The path specified in a `Disallow` rule is simply a prefix. (Therefore a "wildcard" `*` is never required at the end of the path.)

Comment: This is incorrect. [Google *will* still list content blocked by robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en).

Comment: To remove all the images on your site from our index, place the following robots.txt file in your server root:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /

Comment: Google has introduced increased flexibility to the robots.txt file standard through the use asterisks. Disallow patterns may include "*" to match any sequence of characters, and patterns may end in "$" to indicate the end of a name.

Comment: To remove all files of a specific file type (for example, to include .jpg but not .gif images), you'd use the following robots.txt entry:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*.gif$

By specifying Googlebot-Image as the User-agent, the images will be excluded from Google Image Search.

Refer: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en

Answer (score -3):

No Allow code? 
Try add

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /upload/
Disallow: /admin/
```